# how to make npm install dependencies on custom location and avoid wrapping in node_modules?

Tags: angular, dependencies, npm-install

I have published a package parent-package which has a dependency which is another package named child-package which is already published on npm. When I install parent-package, it is wrapped in node_modules and its dependencies are also wrapped in node_modules on the same level as parent-package. I don't want parent_package to be wrapped in node_modules and child-package should be stored under projects folder because in my case child-package is an independent library which will be used in parent-package. According to the default behavior, my folder structure look like this;

`Present Working Director:
|-- node_modules
    |-- parent-package
    |-- child-package
    |-- other dependencies`

I want to achieve this folder structure on installation by default;

`Present Working Director:
|-- parent-package
    |-- projects
        |-- child-package
        |-- other libraries
    |-- src`

How can I change the default behavior of npm installation to achieve this structure? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go two, three (or more) ways about this: the npm way and the Angular way.

### The npm way

One way is to use `postinstall` script for npm - executed, as you suspect, after the package is installed. A naive example follows.

Add this to `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "./postinstall.sh"
}
```

And create a `postinstall.sh` bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -r node_modules/parent_project .
cp -r node_modules/child_package ./parent_project
...other things to copy.
```

This would create the structure you want.

Note that there are a few issues with this. One would be, this is not exactly cross-platform. Another issue is that it would fail on some older npm versions (which nest dependencies in nested node_modules). Finally, I would be very wary of a package that copies scripts directly to my source folders, possibly overwriting things unless it was explicitly specified and said.

All of these issues can be taken care of, but require some thought.

### The Angular way

The Angular way is actually a few of them. The most straight-forward one is to create an Angular Schematic and publish that, instead of the library directly.

When I use an npm library, I *expect* it to be in node_modules, not in my sources. I don't want it in my sources, just the things I actually export. E.g. `@angular/core` itself is in node_modules, and it doesn't get in my way.

#### Schematics

But when I *do* want this library to help me out somehow, I want it to be explicit - by calling a command. And Angular Schematics give you this.

It would be far too complex for a stackoverflow answer to go into details of your question. You better read up on Schematics online, e.g. [this](https://medium.com/rocket-fuel/angular-schematics-simple-schematic-76be2aa72850e) tutorial could help you. And then if you get stuck with specifics, come back to SO with specific questions.

#### Monorepo

Another possible way, if you're only developing the package for yourself, is to use a Monorepo strategy, and, say, ng-packager to work on your "child packages" and libraries.

### Other generators

You could also do this as a yeoman generator, standalone github package, or many other ways to generate some sources. Look into code generation tools, setup your thing as a code template and use the code generator to replicate the desired structure.

---

**Edit:** you mention in comments you want to go "the npm way", but you menton a use case where you seem to want both a npm library and editable package in one.  So why not treat it so? It is clearly not just the "npm way" because having sources modified is not what npm install/update mechanism is for - it's there to manage dependencies.

The simplest way to have it both ways (pun intended) is to use npm install/update mechanism for managing the "use as library" use case, and regular git for "use as source" use case.

Have your parent project as a regular angular project (`new new parent`). Then within that project, also create a library (`ng generate library child`).

Finally, have a reference in `tsconfig` paths to the `dist/library/`, so you only use the "compiled" versions of the library in your parent project.

Now, setup your npm scripts like so:

```
"build.parent": "regular parent build stuff"
"build.child": "build the child library"
"publish.parent": "stuff to publish the parent to npm"
"publish.lib": "ng-packagr stuff to publish the library to npm"
```

So, use cases:

1. You wanna use these simply as npm libraries. Super simple and straight forward.

   npm install parent-package child-package --save-dev
2. You want to have local stuff:

   git clone github.com/you/repo.git

Now you can use a local version and a library version. But seriously, don't. If it's a lib, it's a lib. Otherwise, don't manage it with npm when git is literally created for this, versioning of things.

If you mess with your npm installs, if you go modify sources on doing npm installs, this brings bad things. You want to avoid it.

Howeever, if you really *must* do it, then postinstall scripts should do it. But those scripts really need to be advanced, smart enough to detect that you have updated projects, have sane merge strategies, migrations etc. And you end up actually writing an Angular Schematic, just not with Angular.

Comment: I want to go in npm way. But will it not be problematic on installing updates because of manipulating directory structure manually?

Comment: Actually, I want the child-package to be editable after installation in parent-package so that the user may make desired enhancements in its initial structure and it should also act as a standalone library. If I manipulate the directory structure, it works fine but the problem occurs when I try to update child-package with latest version at npm. NPM tries to look it in node_modules even if try to update it with --prefix parameter like this " npm install --prefix ./projects/  child-package@lates --save " and it don't find it there.

Comment: Continueing previous comment, As a consequence it don't update child-package already placed under projects directory instead creates new directory node_module under projects and places it there as well.